# What this functions in Scheme language do?

Tags: function, functional-programming, scheme

I'm a newbie and I didn't understand very well the language. Could anyone please explain to me what this functions do?

First function:

```
(define (x l)
    (cond
        ((null? l) 0)
        ((list? (car l))
                 (+ (x (car l)) (x (cdr l))))
        (else    (+ 1 (x (cdr l))))
))
```

Second function:

```
(define (x l)
    (cond
        ((null? l) 0)
        ((list? (car l))
                 (+ (x (car l)) (x (cdr l))))
        (else    (+ (car l) (x (cdr l)))
))
```

I do understand the begining but the conditions I didn't understand. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will call your second function `y`.

Writing in pseudocode,

```
x []      ->  0
x [a . b] -> x a + x b    , if list a
x [a . b] -> 1   + x b    , else, i.e. if not (list a)

y []      ->  0
y [a . b] -> y a + y b    , if list a
y [a . b] ->   a + y b    , else, i.e. if not (list a)
```

So for example,

```
x [2,3] = x [2 . [3]]
        = 1    + x [3]
        = 1    + x [3 . []]
        = 1    + (1   + x [])
        = 1    + (1   + 0   )
```

and

```
y [2,3] = y [2 . [3]]
        =    2 + y [3]
        =    2 + y [3 . []]
        =    2 + (  3 + y [])
        =    2 + (  3 + 0   )
```

See? The first counts *something* in the argument list, the second sums them up.

Of course both functions could be called with some non-list, but then both would just cause an error trying to get `(car l)` in the second clause, `(list? (car l))`.

Answer (score 1):

You might have noticed that the two are almost identical. They both accumulates (fold) over a tree. Both of them will evaluate to 0 on the empty tree and both of them will sum the result of the same procedure on the `car` and `cdr` when the car is a `list?`. The two differ when the `car` is not a list and in the first it adds 1 for each element in the other it uses the element itself in the addition. It's possible to write the same a little more compact like this:

```scm
 (define (sum l)
  (cond
    ((null? l) 0)                            ; null-value
    ((not (pair? l)) l)                      ; term
    (else (+ (sum (car l)) (sum (cdr l)))))) ; combine
```

Here is a generalisation:

```scm
(define (accumulate-tree tree term combiner null-value)
  (let rec ((tree tree))
    (cond ((null? tree) null-value)
          ((not (pair? tree)) (term tree))
          (else (combiner (rec (car tree)) 
                          (rec (cdr tree)))))))
```

You can make both of your procedures in terms of `accumulate-tree`:

```scm
(define (count tree)
  (accumulate-tree tree (lambda (x) 1) + 0))

(define (sum tree)
  (accumulate-tree tree (lambda (x) x) + 0))
```

Of course you can make a lot more than this with `accumulate-tree`. It doesn't have to turn into an atomic value.

```scm
(define (double tree)
  (accumulate-tree tree (lambda (x) (* 2 x)) cons '()))

(double '(1 2 ((3 4) 2 3) 4 5)) ; ==> (2 4 ((6 8) 4 6) 8 10)
```